# Cookie установить флаг "secure"

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, cookie, docker-compose

Есть два докер контейнера. 1)nginx 2)nodejs.

HTTPS сертификат только на nginx. Куки отправляются с nodejs. Между контейнерами http, то есть с флагом "Secure" cookie не пойдут.;

Как в nginx поставить на cookie флаг "secure"?

Comment: а они точно "не пройдут"? "не пройдут" в какую сторону - от бэка клиенту или от клиента к бэку?

Comment: Точно, не пойдут.

Comment: в каком направлении?

Comment: С сервера клиенту. Решил уже, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В конфигурацию сервера, в [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) дописать

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Так как у меня express, у него вставляем `proxy: true`.

Пример:

```
app.use(express.session({
  proxy: true,
  secret: 'pass',
  cookie: {
    secure: true
  }            
}));
```

Comment: `Так как у меня express, - у него вставляем proxy: true` плз, поясни в ответе нормально, куда именно это вставлять. Я, например, не понимаю. Добавь кусочек кода